# How to let users add additional content to a page in Rails/Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery, jquery-plugins

Basically, I'm writing an app where users can list their past employers and respective job titles, and would like to have a button they can click to add another entry. I have the back end set up, but I'd like for them to start out with one entry such as:

Employer1: (info goes here)

(Add another employer button)

and upon clicking that button, the page now looks like:

Employer1: (info...)

Employer2: (forms to submit info, upon submission this entry looks just like the one above)

(add another employer button)

 and then so on. I know there has to be a javascript plugin that can do this, but I don't know what this is called and hence haven't been able to find one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would write it yourself.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var form=document.getElementById('myform');
var employers=document.getElementById('employers');

function addEmployer(currID) {
    var employer = currID;
    var nextEmployer = employer+1;
    var employerclone=document.getElementById('employer[employer]').cloneNode(true);
    employerclone.setAttribute('id', 'employer[(nextEmployer)]');
    employers.appendChild(employerclone);
}
</script>
```

and then the form:

```
<form id="myform">
<div id="employers">
    <div id="employer[0]">
        Employer Name:<input type="text" id="employerName[0]">
        Employer Details:<input type="textarea" id="employerDeets[0]">
        <input type="button" value="Add Employer" onclick="addEmployer(this.id)" id="0">
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

This is by no means tested and just a scribble but just the way in which I would go about it. You would also have to set the ids of the inputs so that there is no confusion with the processing once the form has been submitted.